# How to filter by subject and age?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to delete sent items that contain "invoice" in the subject that are more than 30 days old.

It works for emails older than 30 days but doesn't applying the filter on the subject.

The code I'm currently using

```vb
Sub MoveAgedMail()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objVariant As Variant
    Dim lngMovedItems As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim intDateDiff As Integer
    Dim strDestFolder As String
    
    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    
    Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

    Filter = "[Subject] = '%" & "invoice" & "%' And [SenderEmailAddress] = _
    'abc @hotmail.com'"

    Set Items = objSourceFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
        DoEvents
        If objVariant.Class = olMail Then
            
            intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)
             
            If intDateDiff > 30 Then

                objVariant.Move objDestFolder
              
                'count the # of items moved
                lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1

            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Moved " & lngMovedItems & " messages(s)."
    Set objDestFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must work with a restricted set of items instead of getting a new items collection, for example:

```
 For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
   Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
```

It should be rewritten as the following:

```
 For intCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
   Set objVariant = Items.Item(intCount)
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Items as a variable.

```vb
Sub MoveAgedMail()

'Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application

'Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objNamespace As NameSpace

'Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objSourceFolder As Folder

'Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objDestFolder As Folder

Dim objVariant As Variant
Dim lngMovedItems As Long
Dim intCount As Integer

'Dim Items As Outlook.Items ' Do not use Items as a variable
Dim resItems As Items

Dim Filter As String
Dim intDateDiff As Integer
Dim strDestFolder As String

'Set objOutlook = Application   ' not necessary
'Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Debug.Print "objSourceFolder.Items.Count: " & objSourceFolder.Items.Count

Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

' ?
Filter = "[Subject] = '%" & "invoice" & "%' And [SenderEmailAddress] =" 'abc @hotmail.com'"
Debug.Print Filter

Filter = "[Subject] = '%" & "invoice" & "%'"
Debug.Print Filter

Set resItems = objSourceFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
Debug.Print "objSourceFolder.Items.Count: " & objSourceFolder.Items.Count
Debug.Print "resItems.Count: " & resItems.Count

'For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
For intCount = resItems.Count To 1 Step -1

    Set objVariant = resItems.Item(intCount)

    DoEvents

    If objVariant.Class = olMail Then

        intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)

        If intDateDiff > 30 Then

            objVariant.Move objDestFolder

            'count the # of items moved
            lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1

        End If
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Moved " & lngMovedItems & " messages(s)."
Set objDestFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```